Регистрация Аутентификация и Авторизация tg web app
делал веб сайт к нему есть сервер. Встроил это все в бота telegram. При нажатии на кнопку открывает сайт. Проблема: надо показать каждому пользователю свои данные из БД. Не знаю как это реализовать, пытался по chatId передать каждому свое значение но у всех на фронте показывает данные только одного пользователя. Код возможно страшный не обращайте внимание я новичок.
Задача: Вывести уникальному пользователю его данные из бд
Данные для подключения убрал так как Бд на облачном и с других IP не даст подключиться все равно
Backend:
const express = require('express')
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002
const {useState, useEffect} = require('react')
const bodyParser =require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser())
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Сервер запущен на ${PORT} порту`)
})
const WebApps = "https://backend-drc.ru"
const token = ""
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  database: "",
  password: ""
})
connection.connect(function(err){
  if(err) {
      return console.error(`Ошибка подключения! Код: `+ err)
  }else{
      console.log(`Покдлючение к БД успешно установлено!`)
  }
})
const bot = new TelegramApi(token, {polling: true})
  bot.on('message', async msg =>{
  const text = msg.text;
  const uggs = msg.chat.username;
  const chatids = msg.chat.id;
  let Users = Boolean
  let UserActive = null
  if(text === '/start'){
    await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`chatids` = "+chatids, (err, results) =>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return;
      }
      if(results.length <= 0){
        console.log(results)
        Users = false
      }
      else{
        Users = true
        UserActive = results[0].chatids
        console.log(results)
      }
      console.log(UserActive)
    })
    await bot.sendPhoto(chatids, "Logo.png")
    await bot.sendMessage(chatids,"Dragon Village is build",{
      reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard:[
          [{text:'Go to Dragon village', web_app:{url: WebApps}}]
        ]
      }
    })
  }
app.get('/back', (req, res) => {
      connection.execute("SELECT `Dragons` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`chatids` ="+chatids, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
        res.json({
          dragons: results[0].Dragons
        });
        console.log(results)
      });
    });
    app.get('/back5',(req, res) =>{
      connection.execute("SELECT `DRGcoin` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`chatids` ="+chatids, (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
          }
            res.json({
            drg: results[0].DRGcoin
          });
        });
    })
    app.get('/back6',(req, res) =>{
      connection.execute("SELECT `DRCcoin` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`chatids` ="+chatids, (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
          }
            res.json({
            drc: results[0].DRCcoin
          })
          //console.log()
        });
    })
    app.post('/chatback', (req, res) => {
    let data = [req.body.Hunters]
    const zapros = "UPDATE `users` SET `Dragons`=? WHERE `users`.`usnames` =?"
    const params = [data, uggs]
    // const fff = itog
    connection.execute(zapros,params,(err, results) =>{
      !err ? res.json(results) : res.json(err)
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
      /*const ins = "INSERT INTO `users` (`idteleg`,`chatids`, `usnames`, `Dragons`, `Hunters`, `Defends`, `DRCcoin`, `DRGcoin`) VALUES (NULL,?,?,10,0,0,10,100)"
      const into = [chatids, uggs]
      await connection.execute(ins, into,(err, results) =>{
      })
      console.log('Пользователь создан!')*/
  app.get('/back1',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `totBank` FROM `stage`",(err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
          res.json({
          banks: results[0].totBank
        });
      });
  })
  app.get('/back2',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `Seasons` FROM `stage`", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
        }
            res.json({
              seasons: results
      });
   });
  })
  app.get('/back3',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `toStage` FROM `stage`", (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
          res.json({
          stages: results[0].toStage
      });
    });
  })
  app.get('/back4',(req, res) =>{
    connection.execute("SELECT `tOnline` FROM `stage`", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
          res.json({
          online: results[0].tOnline
        });
      });
  })
  function ValidUser() {
    const sasa = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`usnames` = ?"
    const ssss = [uggs]
    connection.execute(sasa,ssss, (err, results) =>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return;
      }
      const param = results[0].chatids
      console.log(results)
      return param
    })
  }
})

app.use(cors())

Поля season stage  и totbank online общие, а dragons DRCcoin DRGcoin индивидуальные
Взял из бд нужный chatId и делал проверку на сравнение тоже не работает.
Frontend https://github.com/O4ko-Samp/StackOwer.git
Буду ооочень рад намекам и помощи.
PS: регистрации нет, при нажатии кнопки в боте надо сразу отображать его данные

Надо в полях Dragons, DRGcoin, DRCcoin каждый пользователь видел свои значения из БД. А у меня получается что один активизировал бота и все его значение показывается всем.

chatid не похож на id пользователя + вы везде выборку режете и возвращаете только первую строку. Какой результат вы вообще хотите получить?

Хочу что бы при клике кнопки в тг боте открывался сайт, там есть 3 поля уникальные. Что бы пользователь перешел на сайт через tg web app и видел в профиле свои данные. Допустим Dragons: 50. Сейчас если перейти показывает всем значение Dragons того кто первый ввел /start. А хочу что бы показывало именно его значение из БД, а не значение того кто первый ввел /start

Проверил несколько раз. Захожу с первого tg аккаунта и пишу /start и перехожу на сайт, отображается то что нужно(Dragons:11). Но если в этот же момент зайдет еще один пользователь и напишет старт то ему так же показывает Dragons:11. т.е значение первого аккунта

Смотрите, что приходит с клиента. Какие значения подставляются в ваши переменные. Какой ответ от БД вы получаете, что возвращаете. Т.е. надо обложиться отладочной информацией. Отдельно обратите внимание на const chatids = msg.chat.id;. Возможно, ваши app.[get/post] обработчики создаются как раз после первой команды старт, и получается, что часть переменных как раз становится "глобальной"

Дело в том что cервер берет запись из БД первого кто написал /start и передает его в GET, а фронт получает именно те данные которые принадлежат первому кто ввел /start. В общем и целом есть ли другое решение что бы не заморачиваться? Мне надо в сервере взять из бд данные пользователя(который открыл Web App) и на фронте показать ему его данные из таблицы в БД. Надо что бы хоть 1000 пользователей откроют одновременно что бы каждый получил свое значение из БД

Еще заметил что get запрос который отправляет сервер значение Dragons после первого использования остается статичной. Как будто взял один раз в однопотоке и держит пока не перезагрузишь сервер. А затем все по новой после первого использования статичный. Никак не соображаю как взять данные из БД на сервере и  передать на фронт таким образом что бы каждый пользователь получал свое значение

Вынесите все ваши app за пределы if. Я уже писал об этом, вы игнорируете. Данные надо получать из каждого запроса, а не из первого

Вынес, все так же когда пользователь заходит в бота один раз берется его chatid и по его id из БД берется значение Dragons который показывается всем
